# Date picker troubleshooting

Tags: date, datetimepicker

I am trying to fill an online form but the date pickers are not functioning properly. Several will not open and others will open but when I submit the form, it will not be sent claiming that some of the fields are not filled when I have used a date picker to fill them. The website belongs to someone else and I am only trying to fill in the online form.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a [datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) your looking for, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) offers one of the best I have seen